# Scala Pickling and type parameters

Tags: scala, scala-pickling

I'm using [Scala Pickling](https://github.com/scala/pickling), an automatic serialization framework for Scala.
According to the [author's slides](http://lampwww.epfl.ch/~hmiller/files/oopsla-pickling.pdf), any type `T` can be pickled as long as there is an implicit `Pickler[T]` in scope.
Here, I'm assuming she means `scala.tools.nsc.io.Pickler`.
However, the following does not compile:

```
import scala.pickling._
import scala.pickling.binary._
import scala.tools.nsc.io.Pickler

object Foo {
  def bar[T: Pickler](t: T) = t.pickle
}
```

The error is:

```
[error] exception during macro expansion:
[error] scala.ScalaReflectionException: type T is not a class
[error]     at scala.reflect.api.Symbols$SymbolApi$class.asClass(Symbols.scala:323)
[error]     at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$SymbolContextApiImpl.asClass(Symbols.scala:73)
[error]     at scala.pickling.PickleMacros$class.pickleInto(Macros.scala:381)
[error]     at scala.pickling.Compat$$anon$17.pickleInto(Compat.scala:33)
[error]     at scala.pickling.Compat$.PickleMacros_pickleInto(Compat.scala:34)
```

I'm using Scala 2.10.2 with scala-pickling 0.8-SNAPSHOT.

Is this a bug or user error?

EDIT 1: The same error arises with both `scala.pickling.SPickler` and `scala.pickling.DPickler`.

EDIT 2: It looks like this is a bug: https://github.com/scala/pickling/issues/31

Comment: I also took recent interest in this project (I believe Heather Miller the creator mentioned it on Stackoverflow on another post).. but I just couldn't find many good examples to get going. Macros are fairly complex based on my current learning curve with Scala, so I wish there were more examples out there. Same applies with Twitter Chill!

Comment: A quick look at the implementation suggests that what you need is not a `scala.tools.nsc.io.Pickler` but a `scala.pickling.SPickler` (or `scala.pickling.DPickler`). Just change your definition to `def bar[T: SPickler](t: T) = t.pickle` and see how it goes.

Comment: No luck with either SPickler or DPickler (see edit).

Comment: Yep, as you've already surmised, but to confirm anyway, you need a `scala.pickling.SPickler` or `scala.pickling.DPickler`. Pay no attention to `scala.tools.nsc.io.Pickler` (this is used by the Scala compiler to pickle/unpickle class files)

Comment: And yep, you're right that there was a pickling/unpickling bug when it came to the pickling framework dealing with abstract types. Thanks for reporting, and hanging in there with us :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yep, as Andy pointed out:

> you need either a [`scala.pickling.SPickler`](https://github.com/scala/pickling/blob/825abf361afb455b3595ff8bf4ce53179458ebd2/core/src/main/scala/pickling/Pickler.scala#L18) or a [`scala.pickling.DPickler`](https://github.com/scala/pickling/blob/825abf361afb455b3595ff8bf4ce53179458ebd2/core/src/main/scala/pickling/Pickler.scala#L33) (static and dynamic, respectively) in order to pickle a particular type.

Those both already come in the `scala.pickling` package, so it's enough to just use them in your generic method signature.

You're absolutely correct that you can add an `SPickler` context-bound to your generic method. The only additional thing which you need (admittedly it's a bit ugly, and we're thinking about removing it) is to add a `FastTypeTag` context bound as well. (This is necessary for the pickling framework to know what type it's trying to pickle, as it handles primitives differently, for example.)

This is what you'd need to do to provide generic pickling/unpickling methods:

Note that for the `unbar` method, you need to provide an `Unpickler` context-bound rather than a `SPickler` context-bound.

```
import scala.pickling._
import binary._

object Foo {
  def bar[T: SPickler: FastTypeTag](t: T) = t.pickle
  def unbar[T: Unpickler: FastTypeTag](bytes: Array[Byte]) = bytes.unpickle[T]
}
```

Testing this in the REPL, you get:

```
scala> Foo.bar(42)
res0: scala.pickling.binary.BinaryPickle =
BinaryPickle([0,0,0,9,115,99,97,108,97,46,73,110,116,0,0,0,42])

scala> Foo.unbar[Int](res0.value)
res1: Int = 42
```

Comment: When using the pickling library, where would a DPickler come into play?

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the project, it seems you need either an [`scala.pickling.SPickler`](https://github.com/scala/pickling/blob/825abf361afb455b3595ff8bf4ce53179458ebd2/core/src/main/scala/pickling/Pickler.scala#L18) or a [`scala.pickling.DPickler`](https://github.com/scala/pickling/blob/825abf361afb455b3595ff8bf4ce53179458ebd2/core/src/main/scala/pickling/Pickler.scala#L33) (static and dynamic, respectively) in order to pickle a particular type.

The pickle methods are macros. I suspect that if you pickle with an `SPickler`, the macro will require the compile time type of your class to be known.

Thus, you may need to do something similar to:

```
object Foo {
  def bar(t: SomeClass1) = t.pickle
  def bar(t: SomeClass2) = t.pickle
  def bar(t: SomeClass3) = t.pickle
  // etc
}
```

Alternatively, a `DPickler` may do the trick. I suspect that you'll still have to write some custom pickling logic for your specific types.